# How do you pass two inputs to model.predict in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

When I run the following code,

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.uint64)
inp2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.uint64)

m = tf.math.floormod(inp1, inp2)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=(inp1, inp2), outputs=[m])

input_data = [[11], [2]]
model.predict(x=input_data)
```

No matter what I do, I always get this error:

```
ValueError: Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>]
```

I have tried various combinations like changing the square brackets to round brackets, but nothing seems to work. This is the `model.summary()` output:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                              
 input_2 (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]          0           []                               
                                                                                              
 tf.math.floormod (TFOpLambda)  (None, 1)            0           ['input_1[0][0]',                
                                                              'input_2[0][0]']                
                                                                                              
==================================================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

How do I pass on multiple inputs through `model.predict`? Even the documentation was not of much help here. This is all I got from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) (The description of argument `x`):

> Input samples. It could be:
>
> A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs).
>
> A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).
>
> A tf.data dataset.
>
> A generator or keras.utils.Sequence instance. A more detailed description of unpacking behavior for iterator types (Dataset,generator, Sequence) is given in the Unpacking behavior for iterator-like inputs section of Model.fit.

When I change the above code to the following (making it accept only one input), the result is as expected:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.uint64)
#inp2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.uint64)

m = tf.math.floormod(inp1, inp1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=(inp1), outputs=[m])

input_data = [[11], [2]]
model.predict(x=input_data)
```

The output was,

```
array([[0], [0]], dtype=uint64)
```

So how do I make my model accept multiple inputs?

(The TensorFlow version I am using is 2.7.0)

*Even if I change the operation to addition, I get the exact same behavior. It works for a single input but not for multiple inputs.*

I have added a gist pointing to the problem, to allow you to quickly recreate the problem: https://gist.github.com/sreramk1/f7813404c8575e0b7680d6efd937688b

Comment: Did you try to provide the inputs as one tuple?
Instead of [[11], [2]] use (11, 2) ?

Comment: Yes I tried that. I am getting the exact same error. I am doing this in my local notebook. I'll try to create a colab example to recreate the problem

Comment: Try using a list of tensors `input_data = [tf.constant([11]), tf.constant([2])]` or a list of arrays `input_data = [np.array([11]), np.array([2])]` as suggested by the documentation.

Comment: @FlaviaGiammarino thank you very much! You are right, it works! Now I understand: when giving multiple inputs, we must make a distinction between a single tensor and an argument of inputs to resolve the ambiguity.